# External Authentication with ASP.NET Web API 2 - Microsoft not working now

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, identity

I configured External Authentication Services within my ASP.NET Web Api 2 successfully for Facebook, Google, Microsoft & Twitter about a year ago. Revisiting recently I was quickly able to get everything working again for everything besides Microsoft. I originally followed a tutorial similar to [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services#MICROSOFT).

The first error I was getting was below -

/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Microsoft&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.censored.com%2Fapi%2FAccount%2FAuthComplete&state=PgiSt-woFC7HSvc990RM5RXVdkW_ozDKy3PDpDeyeAU1&client_id=censored&**error=access_denied** HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=0000000

I deleted the app at [https://apps.dev.microsoft.com](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) thinking re-adding it may fix the problem to discover I was unable to re-add it in such a way as to generate a ClientId & Client Secret. Has Microsoft support for OAuth completely changed and what do I have to do now?

Here is part of Startup class that shows how I am configuring Facebook & Microsoft OAuth.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { g

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please 
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // working 
        var fbook = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "sadfsda",
            AppSecret = "dsfsadf"
        };
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fbook);

        // not working
        var msoft = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "sadf",
            ClientSecret = "zdfsdf",
        };
        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(msoft);
```

Comment: What version of Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount are you using?

Comment: The latest - 3.1.0

Comment: If your claims contains an email claim, you might have to work around it until the next version of Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.


See [https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/48](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/48) and [https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/pull/89](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/pull/89),

Comment: It doesn't contain an email claim. Just the very basic. Do you know if I'm supposed to use ApplicationId and Password instead of ClientId and ClientSecret from https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this after reading some of the comments from the GitHub link. I created a new App at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com  skipping the guided setup. Then I retrieved the password with the *Generate New Password* button. This and the application Id (a guid) I used for the ClientId and ClientSecret. Added a Redirect URL e.g.

```
https://www.sadfsdaf.com/signin-microsoft
```

and it worked.